Why isn't my scrapy pagination by brand using counter working?
Code isn't working. I'm trying to scrape multiple pages from differents brands (categories). The page that I'm using have a list of all the brands. The brands are arranged in groups, which are classified by the initial letter of that brand. And inside the page of this brands, there are multiple pages os differents products that the brand has.
Tried to do a code that takes the brand using a counter, and if there are no brands in this specific first-letter-group, it goes to the next gorup. (The request is fine, the problem is in the code. The scrape by itself is working, only when I try this pagination that the code fails).
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class MlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ml"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/produtos-cabelo')

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        cgroup = 1
        cbrand = 1
        num_group = response.xpath(f'//div[@class="ui-search-search-modal-filter-group"][{cgroup}]').get()
        for m in num_group:
            link_marca = m.xpath(f'.//a[@class="ui-search-search-modal-filter ui-search-link"][{cbrand}]/@href').get()
            if link_marca:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=link_marca)
                for i in response.xpath('.//div[@class="ui-search-result__content"]'):
                    marca = i.xpath('.//span[@class="ui-search-item__brand-discoverability ui-search-item__group__element"]/text()').get()
                    title = i.xpath('.//h2/text()').get()
                    real = i.xpath('.//span[@class="andes-money-amount ui-search-price__part ui-search-price__part--medium andes-money-amount--cents-superscript"]//span[@class="andes-money-amount__fraction"]/text()').get()
                    centavo = i.xpath('//span[@class="andes-money-amount ui-search-price__part ui-search-price__part--medium andes-money-amount--cents-superscript"]//span[@class="andes-money-amount__cents andes-money-amount__cents--superscript-24"]/text()').get()
                    value = f'R$ {real},{centavo}'
                    link = i.xpath('.//a/@href').get()

                    yield {
                        'marca': marca,
                        'title': title,
                        'value': value,
                        'link': link
                    }

                next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Seguinte")]/@href').get()
                if next_page:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

                cbrand += 1

            else:
                cgroup += 1


Your pagination isn't working because of your placement of the next page logic. I have edited your code such that it starts from the brands page and then goes to each brand, gets the product details and if there's a next page it will go to the next page and scrape the products on that page. I have also edited some of your selectors as below:
import scrapy


class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["lista.mercadolivre.com.br"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/produtos-cabelo_FiltersAvailableSidebar?filter=BRAND"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        brand_links = response.xpath("//div[@class='ui-search-search-modal-grid-columns']/a/@href").getall()

        for link in brand_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_products)

    def parse_products(self, response):
        for i in response.xpath('.//div[@class="ui-search-result__content"]'):
            marca = i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "ui-search-item__brand-discoverability")]/text()').get()
            title = i.xpath(".//h2/text()").get()
            real = i.xpath('.//span[@class="andes-money-amount__fraction"]/text()').get()
            centavo = i.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "andes-money-amount__cents")]/text()').get()
            value = f"R$ {real},{centavo}"
            link = i.xpath(".//a/@href").get()

            yield {
                "marca": marca,
                "title": title,
                "value": value,
                "link": link,
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Seguinte")]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_products)

